# JsonObject Stream Handling Nulls

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to put JsonObject values to a custom ArrayList using Streams

```
    List<MyClass> custom = new ArrayList<>();
```

I map the stream to JsonObject

```
.map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
                .forEach(jsonObject -> custom.add(new MyClass(
                        jsonObject.get("stuff1").getAsString(),
                        jsonObject.get("stuff2").getAsString(),
                        jsonObject.get("stuff3").getAsLong(),
                        jsonObject.get("stuff4").getAsInt())));
```

and try to add it, everything works fine.

but the value `stuff4` can be missing from the jsonObject (server did not send a `stuff4` JsonObject attribute) and thats where I am getting the null pointer exception. Does anyone knows how I can handle this using the gson lib? an answer with `stream#collect` instead of `stream#forEach` would be nice as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Gson library imported, then you can do the following:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();


.map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
                .forEach(jsonObject -> custom.add(gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(),MyClass.class)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
                .forEach(jsonObject -> custom.add(new MyClass(
                        jsonObject.get("stuff1").getAsString(),
                        jsonObject.get("stuff2").getAsString(),
                        jsonObject.get("stuff3").getAsLong(),
                        jsonObject.get("stuff4")==null? null:jsonObject.get("stuff4").getAsInt())));
```

Or

```
.map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
                    .forEach(jsonObject -> custom.add(new MyClass(
                            ...
                            jsonObject.has("stuff4")? jsonObject.get("stuff4").getAsInt():null)));
```

Comment: I wan't to see if there is a gson way of doing this, Like org.json has `opt` method to check for nulls.

Comment: I guess if "stuff4" may be null, there should be a check as in Khalid's answer.  You may have to provide a valid resolution in those cases(maybe you have to give any default value/ pass null itself as 4th argument)

Comment: @James null pointer exception occures when you use `.getAsInt()` from which is not exist.
you have to check before getting `jsonObject.has("stuff4")`